# How can I create and use a MySQL statement with MySQL++ library

Tags: c++, mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to create a MySQL statement with MySQL++ library, but I can't find how to do it. I found something called query templates, but, is it like a real MySQL statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was just checking out [this](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/userman/tquery.html) and it looks like using template queries is, in part, the means by which an SQL statement is passed to MySQL++. So I guess that would be, in part, the route to take to create a MySQL statement with MySQL++.

```
    // Establish the connection to the database server.
    mysqlpp::Connection con(mysqlpp::examples::db_name,
            cmdline.server(), cmdline.user(), cmdline.pass());

    // Build a template query to retrieve a stock item given by
    // item name.
    mysqlpp::Query query = con.query(
            "select * from stock where item = %0q");
    query.parse();
```

Also, in response to:

> is it like a real MySQL statement?

What's going on is that the compiler is taking your c++ code which contains the statement that you want to execute and then communicating with the MySQL db for you, at which point the 'real' SQL statement is used.

Comment: First of all, thanks Drew for the reply. The thing is that I was looking inside the library and I don't see in it when it sends the statement to the server to be compiled. I'm worried it just parse the statement and execute it like a simple query.

Comment: Welcome. And gotcha. So you're worried that your query might not be correctly executed by the code that handles the query in the MySQL++ library?

Comment: I'm worried that the execution time is more if the statement is executed as a query and not like a compiled statement. :)

Comment: Ahhh gotcha. I think all queries are statements, but not all statements are queries. Also, I think the query function is used for all statements if that makes sense?

Comment: I guess I just don't think there are separate functions to handle selects/updates/deletes/inserts...

Comment: But if you look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-prepared-statements.html you could see, that a C prepared statement is more eficient than a simple query. When the intention is to execute it more than once.

Comment: Oh cool--I didn't know that! Do you know if the MySQL++ supports C prepared statements?

Comment: That was part of my question. :)

Comment: Haha ahh gotcha. Yeah, I could be wrong, but it doesn't look like to me that it supports C prepared statements! Also, sorry for any confusion!

Comment: ok, I'll keep then the post unsolved, to check if someone know the anwser. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to use the query() public member function of the Connection class.

There is no real need to use templates, although you can if you want to.

The query() function takes an SQL statement as string value and returns a Query object.

The class' query functions are defined as follows:

- query (const std::string &qstr)
- query (const char *qstr=0)

You can find lots of details in the [reference guide](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/refman/annotated.html).

Comment: thanks for the reply Dave, do you know what means mysqlpp::MultiStatementsOption in MySQL++?